# Cordova overwrites bundle identifier after changing it

Tags: ios, cordova, bundle-identifier

I'm developing an IOS app using cordova, the problem is that I created the project with the wrong bundle identifier.

After I changed it, if I execute: `cordova build` the bundle identifier gets overwritten to the original, the one I don´t want.

I tried changing the id in .cordova/config.json, however, the problem persist.

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to set your bundle identifier with

```
<widget id="my.bundle.identifier" version="0.6" ...
```

in the file `www/config.xml`.

Comment: Is it correct that from the config.xml the iOS project will be generated? I'm quite new to cordova. If i change the widget id will it have any side effects? What i've done is changed the widget id in the config.xml and the product bundle name within the iOS project.